# Indexed .lzo log files performing slower than .gz compressionxt

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, lzo

I have some log files compressed at lzo setting 7 and gzip at default compression and my results are as follows:

MapReduce job over:

- 1GB .gz file - 340 seconds
- 1GB .lzo file un-indexed - 410 seconds
- 1GB .lzo file indexed - 380 seconds

The MapReduce job simply utilizes the Hadoop-LZO library's LzoTextInputFormat class instead of the usual TextInputFormat class. That's the only difference.

I see 37 map tasks come through and split up the job and use the .index file, but the performance leaves a lot to be desired. Any ideas?

Comment: Try your job with 2 or 4 mappers only. 37 seems to big a number for 1 Gb file.

Comment: 1 GB is the compressed size or the un-compressed size ?